# How can I resolve dependencies I cloned a maven project for my work but I am facing dependency issues

Tags: maven, cucumber-java

Facing below issue not sure what is actually missing
please help me with this  one
Trying to run my Maven project but facing dependency issue
Need to run without any issues

```
WARNING[m] The POM for test:generateBearerToken:jar:0.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[[1;33mWARNING[m] The POM for com.nm.esb:generate-token:jar:0.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time:  2.733 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2023-03-04T12:30:02+05:30
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
 Failed to execute goal on project [36mNMG_MAWM[m: [1;31mCould not resolve dependencies for project NMG_MAWM:NMG_MAWM:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: test:generateBearerToken:jar:0.1.0, com.nm.esb:generate-token:jar:0.1.0: test:generateBearerToken:jar:0.1.0 was not found in file://C:\Users\vs004759\git\mawm/lib/generateBearerToken.jar during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of lib has elapsed or updates are forced[m -> [1m[Help 1][m
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
 Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: You are trying to use an artifact that is not available in maven central or has been installed on your machine earlier.  Why do you expect this to work?